# `sum` function not working as expected in case of large strings

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, `#sum` is used to calculate

1. Sum of array
2. Sum of an array based on a function or condition
3. Sum of `ASCII` codepoints (`ord`) in a string (not char array) i.e. `'abcd'.sum # => 394`

The problem with the third one is the following

For the string below,

```
AwotIJHOAIJSRoieJHOjasOIADaoiHAOHJAOIJGOIajdOIQWJTOIGJDOINCOIASORIOGIMAOIMEORIQEMOIGMEOIFMASKDJQOWJGOJOASJOIQWOGIMASOIDMOQWIROQIGJOIAMSFOAIJGIHIWUNVNZMXCNXCKJQOWRIEOGSDGSPOKSDLAMKMROQIJRDFLKMZXOIAJSQPIRKLMAdglkaSFAJOIAJFOIQWJEOIQJKAMCLKACMALKSDLAKWEQANLEIRJRQFIJAOIVAWOTIJHOAIJSROIEJHOJASOIADAOIHAOHJAOIJGOIAJDOIQWJTOIGJDOINCOIASORIOGIMAOIMEORIQEMOIGMASODLQWKEJOIFJLKMALSKQIOWELKMZLXKMFALSFJQOIWEAOISFWIDHGPSODRJAWOPIJHOIDJOIAJTGIOJAORAJWOIJHOFMAOIFMOIPDMOAIPWJTOPIJDOIFjawoiRJOIpjmaioGJIGHAIJRHQHQIUEIvnaksJDNWIORQIOPEGHIDVNAJKNASIPHRQEUITHIUHDNAJSNWIHJQIWJQEOIGOIDVNAKOSDNAOPWPJQOPIWTJQEOIPGDPJFNASPJNQWOIRQWIOTOIVNAKSFNAIOAWOTIJHOAIJSROIEJHOJASOIADAOIHAOHJAOIJGOIAJDOIQWJTOIGJDOINCOIASORIOGIMAOIMEORIQEMOIGMASODLQWKEJOIFJLKMALSKQIOWELKMZLXKMFALSFJQOIWEAOISFWIDHGPSODRJAWOPIJHOIDJoiajTGIOJAORAJWOIJHOFMAOIFMOIPDMOAIPWJTOPIJDOIFJAWOIRJOIPJMAIOGJIGHAIJRHQHQIUEIVNAKSJDNWIORQIOPEGHIDVIPNWIHJQIWJQEOIGOIDVNAKOSDNAOPWPJQOPIWTJqeoIPGDPJFNASPJNQWJQWOIRJgonasKFAWOEJQWOIJOGALKFNASLFKqeqOFIJAOISFJAOISFJAWOI
```

which is large, (of `1000` characters), the following program doesn't work

```rb
putc gets.upcase.sum/~/$/
```

It works for all other strings of lesser size. The output of the above must be `K`. But it shows `\9`

But if I do this

```rb
putc gets.upcase.chars.sum(&:ord)/~/$/
```

It shows `K`. But the former one gives the correct output for all the other string except the large ones like this.

What is wrong here?

#### EDIT : Try it Online link

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VNNbxMxEL3nV3BACC7tnZsVf814veOPJI56W5KoJKXdJptQceGvh/FSIUQv5YZQLqvRzHvj957Xh9Onb@fz4@m4enO7OQ5Xp8dVN2yuhtP99ffrt9cTngyTF@PV5@4wVND7dx/7w/rDiD2fxVN/BLQkAHPqtxsud91AIGTXb60gi4IADUG3WxPEgjMCg5KgnTIoUwIy4BnjFddReR5zCdqL7CRGKkxGEhkre8RmAukpFkgUeRev8VlXAQYslHm7aG/8ctoup67SEygyWZocyGXZCO985WGSunH@Zsl0zDFAco0X69svd13Woi5FPeplLRGd8NPGiakXzbjEFRVF2yhImKKG6nEhCs1@JUGguMSqVUie/p6EqPZfmQT3ZROLU6xIIwsWTXYRqKgqvlk6r7mj2SgUxdysC0hrAtMSsqJQFYEc/cwMsCJKAgvVtq6HaT4mcJwCQlXEeFakd91Tv03Metzdd9veIBjLvpKNNsJcwdeH7m5A2RagxGqCMhbkohXoWpEh2BTVHGYW5lZyMzPOYoSCkdPkBCrUUeYZhRJYfIAyG4fByICalwRs@boh8TUTB1UJmftA/3TM/bbb/UXMlQo15oCerb2IeXT9ImYIr8tzv@n/yBPHSPG2f@gGp/lwNXaQDP/XFdVot9/s6ecfzX6fv4yZXB765aFfHvr//9B/AA)

Comment: Can you remove usage of `gets` and replace it references to that string? Makes it easier for us to try your code.

Comment: Sure. I have added the Try It Online link at the end where the program is already written along with the inputs

Comment: I consider myself a pretty knowledgeable rubyist, but I can't figure out what is the `/~/$/` doing there. Can you elaborate?

Comment: [`String#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#sum-method) returns _"a basic n-bit checksum of the characters in str"_ which is not the same as summing its codepoints.

Comment: To answer my own question: `require 'ripper'; pp Ripper.sexp("gets.updase.sum/~/$/` shows what's what. The key part is [`Regexp#~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-i-7E): "Matches rxp against the contents of $_. Equivalent to rxp =~ $_.". So `~/$/` appears to be a VERY roundabout way of getting length of the input string without the trailing newline.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev [Tips for golfing in Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby)

Comment: @Stefan: thanks, good read for spare time, but I'd prefer if golf-grade code stayed on codegolf.se :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sum of ASCII codepoints (ord) in a string (not char array) i.e. 'abcd'.sum # => 394

I've actually never heard of `String#sum` before, despite being fairly knowledgeable in the language. So I [looked it up](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-sum):

> Returns a basic *n*-bit checksum of the characters in str, where n is the optional Integer parameter, defaulting to 16. The result is simply the sum of the binary value of each byte in *str* modulo `2**n - 1`. This is not a particularly good checksum.

And sure enough, using your example input string, that's why we get:

```
str.chars.map(&:ord).sum
  # => 77090
str.sum
  # => 11554
```

The values are different because `77090 > 2**15`. Moreover, `77090 % 2**15 == 11554`.

If you use a larger value for `n`, the (check)sum is what you expected:

```
str.sum(100)
  #=> 77090
```

Comment: And if you ask me, that method should *not* be in the core language, and it should be given a more descriptive name -- e.g. `CheckSum.calculate(string)`  instead of `string.sum`.

Comment: It's a very old method: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_0r/string.c#L2092